# Pupil Labs Eye Tracking camera set up, is my video feed inverted?

Tags: unity-game-engine, eye-tracking

I just got Pupil Labs eye tracking headset (just the eye tracking cameras, no world view camera, regular headset not VR). I am using pupil labs capture software to get a video feed of my eyes and track my pupils to use in a Unity app. I noticed that my right eye video feed is inverted (upside down) by default, and I wanted to ask if that was intended or if my headset is somehow defective or incorrectly set-up. I ask because I saw a video of someone setting it up and their videos were both up-right with the correct orientation. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Recommendation of own experiences during my master Thesis: If you have access to **any** other eye tracking hardware .. forget about Pupil Labs ^^ I mean ok it have been about 2 years but back then the software was so full of bugs that my PC bluescreened about every 10 minutes ^^

Comment: @derHugo i dont really have an option unfortunately. do you have any input on my question? when you used your pupil labs eye tracking did it show both eyes with the same orientation or was one inverted?

Comment: I guess they should be the same. However, honestly I never got it to run in Unity really .. I switched to MagicLeap/HoloLens2 ^^

Comment: oh I mean just the pupil capture itself shows one inverted (right eye) and one right side up (left eye). There's an option to flip the image in the video feed but I don't know if that affects the tracking. it's very inaccurate so I was wondering if that's why.

Comment: If I remember correctly they where both upright in PupilLabs itself ... At least both where rotated the same way so yes maybe try to flip it! Is it possible that the camera hardware itself is build in wrong?

Comment: thats what I was wondering, because as I said by default the left eye is the correct orientation while the right eye is upside down. I can flip the image but not sure if that changes the tracking. thanks for your input tho, helps to know it should be upright by default.

Comment: hm unfortunately I also don't know if flipping the image in pupilLabs actually flips the Stream which is passed on to e.g. Unity or only the GUI representation of PupilLabs itself :D but I guess you can try it and see the results in Unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Pupil Labs' [release documentation](https://github.com/pupil-labs/pupil/releases):

> The eye 0 (right eye) camera sensor is physically flipped, which
> results in an upside-down eye image for the right eye. This is by
> design and does not negatively affect pupil detection or gaze
> estimation. However, the upside-down eye 0 image repeatedly led users
> to believe that something was broken or incorrect with Pupil Core
> headsets. We flipped the eye 0 image now by default to better match
> user expectations with a right-side-up eye image.

That is, the hardware intentionally has one camera physically flipped relative to the other. If this is visible to you in the video output, then you should either upgrade the software (which now defaults to flipping the image as required), or apply that setting manually.